# Script that can generate a listing of recently modified files

Tags: linux, scripting, automation, report

Is there a script (PHP?) that I can install (via FTP) and run that will give me a listing of the files that are modified AFTER a particular date on the entire domain?

Comment: Linux?  Windows?  Does it have to be web-based?

Comment: Linux. But I don't have shell or physical access to my server.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Server Fault is not a free script writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been **years** since I've last touched PHP, but if I recall correctly you can call an external (shell) command from it, and suck in the results.  Under that assumption, if the server you're dealing with is a Unix/Linux box, you could call out to the 'find' command and let it do the work.

The basic syntax would be: `find /your/web/root/here/ -mtime -5 -print` if you wanted a list of all files modified in the last 5 days.

Just write a PHP wrapper around that command (modified as needed) to run it and display the results on a page for you.  I think that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to use a PHP wrapper and this basic shellscript:

```
#!/bin/sh
# find all files newer then "2012-10-31 12:09"    
touch -d "2012-10-31 12:09" /tmp/reference
find /path/to/observe -newer /tmp/reference > /path/to/webserver/modified.files
```